# Is there a way to programatically obtain the Task Manager "Users" tab?

Tags: windows, powershell, memory, process, task

The Windows Task Manager (`taskmgr.exe`) has a Users tab that displays a table of user names, session status, total CPU % usage and total memory usage.

Is there a way to obtain this data programatically (via PowerShell for example)?`

I have attempted to use `Get-Process`, and sum each of the fields based on the process's UserName, but I cannot get any figures that match the values shown in Task Manager.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: FYI - this is off-topic here. As the [tag:windows] tag description explains, "GENERAL WINDOWS SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com" - probably best to post on [su]

Answer (score 0):

What about to aggregate processes by user name?

```
Get-Process -IncludeUserName | Group-Object -Property UserName | Select-Object Name, @{ Name='CPU'; Expression={ ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property CPU -Sum).Sum } }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what fields I should be looking at to get the same view as Task Manager. Task Manager claims it is showing Physical Memory, but if I run your code with the PM field, I get something in the many-terabytes range.